# What can cause "Required Package 'IndyCore' not found" when compiling a Delphi 2010 project?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, indy

I have got a fresh install of Delphi 2010 on Windows 8.1.

I create a new project, and under Packages, I select "Build with runtime packages".

I compile it and immediately get the error
"[dcc Fatal Error] E2202 Required package 'IndyCore' not found"

I have checked: The package IndyCore140.bpl is available in the $BDS\bin directory as are all the other Indy related packages. The IndyCore.dcp file is also available in $BDS\lib and $BDS\lib\debug.

This is driving me nuts. Any hints?

This is the command line I get when I enable the "Show command line" option (line breaks added for readability):

```
dcc command line for "Project2.dpr"
c:\delphi\delphi2010\bin\dcc32.exe
  --no-config
  -LUrtl;vcl;vclx;vclimg;vclactnband;dbrtl;vcldb;vcldbx;bdertl;vcltouch;xmlrtl;
    dsnap;dsnapcon;TeeUI;TeeDB;Tee;adortl;VclSmp;vclie;inet;inetdb;webdsnap;
    websnap;inetdbbde;inetdbxpress;soaprtl;DbxCommonDriver;DbxClientDriver;
    DBXInterBaseDriver;DBXMySQLDriver;dbexpress;dbxcds;tdbf;intrawebdb_100_140;
    Intraweb_100_140;IndyCore;IndySystem;IndyProtocols
  -M
  -Q
  -AWinTypes=Windows;WinProcs=Windows;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE
  -DDEBUG
  -Ic:\delphi\delphi2010\lib;"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\dcp"
  -LE"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\Bpl"
  -LN"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\Dcp"
  -NB"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\Dcp"
  -Oc:\delphi\delphi2010\lib;"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\dcp"
  -Rc:\delphi\delphi2010\lib;"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\dcp"
  -Uc:\delphi\delphi2010\lib;"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\dcp"
  -K00400000
  -NO"C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\Dcp"
  Project2.dpr
```

There is nothing suspicious I could find.

EDIT: Stefan Glienke suggested on Google+ to check the PATH environment variable, because it might be too long. It was around 1400 characters long. I reduced it to the bare minimum, 224 characters, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Oh those lovely people that downvote a question without leaving a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question was answered by Daniela Osterhagen in a Google+ post that is no longer available:

> It's probably the indycore.dcp file that the compiler cannot find. Is that file in the library path?
>
> No, it's not! Look at the command line you posted! It doesn't contain
>   c:\delphi\delphi2010\lib\indy10 !
>
> I just temporarily removed that directory from the library path in my Delphi 2010 installation and got the same error.

As it turned out, that was exactly the problem. $(BDS)\libs\Indy10 was missing from the library path. I have no idea how that came to happen, because as said above, this was a fresh install.

(links removed, Google+ is no longer available and the Internet Archive hasn't got them either)

Comment: I have the same problem and found solution from this post. Thanks!