# How to compile GUI code using Delphi 7 command line?

Tags: delphi-7, dcc32

I have Delphi 7 as my IDE, which successfully compiles GUI code through the IDE and creates an executable. I want to compile the same code through the command-line using `dcc32.exe`, which is Delphi 7's compiler. I have a `.cfg` file created by the IDE and a `.dpr` which is my project file.

When I run the following command:

`dcc32.exe -B -Q abc.dpr`

Or:

`dcc32.exe abc.cfg`

Both commands throw the following error:

```
Borland Delphi Version 15.0
Copyright (c) 1983,2002 Borland Software Corporation
Fatal: Required package 'VirtualTreesD7' not found
```

But the same `abc.dpr` file compiles correctly through the Delphi 7 IDE.

Here is my `abc.cfg` file:

```
-$A8
-$B-
-$C+
-$D+
-$E-
-$F-
-$G+
-$H+
-$I+
-$J+
-$K-
-$L+
-$M-
-$N+
-$O-
-$P+
-$Q-
-$R-
-$S-
-$T-
-$U-
-$V+
-$W-
-$X+
-$YD
-$Z1
-GP
-cg
-AWinTypes=Windows;WinProcs=Windows;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE
-H+
-W-
-M
-$M16384,1048576
-K$00400000
-E"C:\bin"
-LE"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl"
-LN"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl"
-U"components\VCLZip\Delphi7;C:\VirtualTreeView-Lazarus-4.8\Source;C:\PngComponents\Source"
-O"components\VCLZip\Delphi7;C:\VirtualTreeView-Lazarus-4.8\Source;C:\PngComponents\Source"
-I"components\VCLZip\Delphi7;C:\VirtualTreeView-Lazarus-4.8\Source;C:\PngComponents\Source"
-R"components\VCLZip\Delphi7;C:\VirtualTreeView-Lazarus-4.8\Source;C:\PngComponents\Source"
-LUVirtualTreesD7
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? I need to compile Delphi 7 GUI code through command-line via a script.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894474/.  Where is the `.dcp` for the `VirtualTreesD7` package located, and is that folder included on the search path you are specifying?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your reply. After either copying .dcp for the VirtualTreesD7 or including the path in search path now my Delphi GUI is compiling through command line as well. Thanks again ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RemyLebeau suggested, I could able to compile Delphi GUI code using following ways
Copying VirtualTreesD7.dcp file in my Delphi GUI Source Code directory
OR
Including the path where VirtualTreesD7.dcp is located in "Search Path" i.e. in .cfg file of my project.

Issue stands resolved now!